# Disabling certain applications on Android 6.0.1

Tags: applications, 6.0-marshmallow, installation, disable-app

I am trying to disable certain applications from being run on our android company issued cellphones. We tried simply downloading Applock on the play store but apparently some employees have gone around this. Is this anything in android that gives you the option to disable installation or running applications? I have root access and all phones running superuser.

Comment: Please read the tags **before** posting your question.

Comment: Just a question: Why have you rooted corporate phones? Also, there is a class of products called "Mobile Device Management" which address this need along with providing centralized management and reporting. You should look into that.

Comment: This isn't a corporate company. Just a small family owned company